# How to add search bar into navigation bar in Xamarin IDE

Tags: ios, user-interface, xamarin, uinavigationbar

How do I add a search bar inside a navigation bar in the Xamarin IDE?  I'm trying to have a search icon on the navigation bar and when that icon is clicked I want the navigation bar to turn into a type-able search box. Similar to the search bar on the twitter mobile app. I am using iOS in the xamairn IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply drag a UISearchBar or a UISearchDisplayController into the UINavigationBar

[image]